# What is cross classification?

Tags: classification, terminology, intuition

I could not find a Wikipedia page, can someone explain to a non-statistician what cross classification is? An example where this technique is used in financial risk assessment (credit risk / market risk) would also be helpful.

Is it the same as cross validation?

Comment: Can you provide an example of your example (i.e. a link or citation)? However, what you may be looking for is a [contigency table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contingency_table).

Comment: Thanks...I cannot provide the source...the source is the examples in the documentation of SAS Risk Dimensions

Answer (score 3):

Cross classification usually means that the data points are classified according to multiple criteria (usually coded as factors, that is, categorical variables) at the same time, giving rise to a [contingency table](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/54774/what-is-contingent-in-a-contingency-table).

This has nothing to do with cross-validation.